# Enable/disable a button depending on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying since this morning to create a code using jQuery that allows to enable/disable a submit button when I click on a checkbox. I am trying to write all this code inside a function that will be called on everyclick.

The problem is that it works fine on JSFiddle, but on my computer one time the button is enabled I cannot make it disabled again by unchecking all checkboxes.

Do you have any idea to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advence.

This is my code:

```js
function activeBouton() {
  var countChecked = function() {
    var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
  if (n == 0) jQuery('button').prop('disabled', true);
 else jQuery('button').prop('disabled', false);
  };
  countChecked(); 
  $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );      
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="activeBouton()">
  <input type="checkbox" name="nom" value="1" /> Item un
  <input type="checkbox" name="nom" value="2" /> Item deux
  <input type="checkbox" name="nom" value="3" /> Item trois
</div>
<button id="activeBtn" disabled>Add</button>
```

Comment: Is your example provided here not working as you intend?

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me

Comment: Which browser is it not working in on your machine?  Is this the exact code that you are using on your machine?

Comment: if it works in the fiddle and not on your machine, it's probably another piece of code which is faulty

Comment: @Lee.Winter, Yea, it works here, but on my computer it doesn't and I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: @NickLarsen, I use Chrome, but even on JSFiddle it doesn't work. It's weird.

Comment: @RifkiAriaGumelar It works on the code snippet, but not on JSFiddle neither on my computer.

Comment: @messerbill https://jsfiddle.net/M33D/6q2bdsfr/

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is because of jQuery version? here on the code snippet I used 1.10.2 and on JSFiddle 1.12.2, on my computer 1.8.2 (I'm working on an old project)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6q2bdsfr/2/ - this one is working now, it was only loaded too late. The version could truley make a difference

Comment: if jsfiddle is also not working for you on your computer then check whether `javascript` is disabled on your browser

Comment: he even could not use this platform (SO) if js was disabled... @RRR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet you shared is bit confusing. `activeBouton` function is attached with `click` handler of the `div`, which is calling `countChecked()` & this is also called if there is any change in `checkbox`

It can be simplified.
Beside in there is a major difference between `LOAD TYPE` like  `onLoad` , `onDOMReady`,`body` & `head` in jsfiddle. So it will be helpful if it is possible to show where you are putting your code when you are running your code in browser

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
function countChecked() {
  if ($('input[name="nom"]:checked').length > 0 && $("#activeBtn").is(':disabled')) {
        $("#activeBtn").removeAttr('disabled')
    } else if ($('input[name="nom"]:checked').length == 0) {
       $("#activeBtn").attr('disabled', true)
    }
};
$('input[name="nom"]').on("change", function(event) {
    countChecked(); // Call countChecked event on change in checkbox
});
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/o1owo30u/5/)

Comment: It works, I started by trying this method, but my real code contains more than 10000 lines and a lot of function, that's why I try to enable/disable a bouton using function (it means the code you wrote inside a function that I can call after at every click)

Comment: It works on JSFiddle, but not on my computer, because as I said, I am trying to put all this code in a function and call it when I click, but it does'nt work at all. Do you know how to put your in a function and call by the next as I did in my first code?

Comment: No, in a js file contains other functions.

Comment: Ok are you seeing body tag in your html or jsp?

Comment: It's a jsp project, and I cannot see any body tag that imports js file. It is an old and complicated project, that's why I try to insert my code in the global js file

Comment: Can you try by this code

$('body').on("change",'input[name="nom"]',function(event) {
    countChecked();
});
Make change on in this part , rest leave as it is

Comment: Finally, I used anonyme function and it works now, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When I attempt to run your fiddle, I get the following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: activeBouton is not defined.

Not sure why you are trying to bind a click event to the div with an `onclick` attribute, when you are already binding click events to the individual checkboxes with jQuery.

Try doing it this way instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var countChecked = function() {
    var n = $("input:checked").length;
    if (n == 0) jQuery('button').prop('disabled', true);
    else jQuery('button').prop('disabled', false);
  };

  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", countChecked);
});
```

And get rid of the `onclick` attribute on your surrounding `<div>`.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6q2bdsfr/3/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I don't wanna use (document).ready because the real file contains more than 10000 line, and a lot of functions, that's why I wanna call a funtion that contains this method to run those instructions.